# How do I replace a backslash-double quote with just a double quote?

Tags: c#

I have struggled with a simple replace. And need a good solution. Background: It is a xml string encoded with \" and these need to be " to be able to deserialize  it with serializer.Deserialize.

I want to replace backslash doublequot with one double quot a string like "  \"hello\"  " so the string are "  "hello"  ". The text is long so it is not possible to remove backslash. Thanks for advise.
I think it should have been

```
string s= "\" teetete \"";
string t;
t = s.Replace("\"", @"""");
```

Comment: regex replace??

Comment: Your sample string doesn't contain a backslash, this does: `string s = "\\\" teetete \\\"";`

Comment: I strongly suspect you're looking in the debugger, but it's hard to tell without more context. If it's actually XML, I wouldn't handle it as a plain string to start with.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, now it works. It was the the debugger that confused me. it shows \".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sample string doesn't contain any backslashes, you are just using it to mask the double quotes. This contains one backslash at the beginning and one at the end:

```
string s = "\\\" teetete \\\"";
```

If you want to replace it with a single double quote:

```
string t = s.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

You have to look click at the loupe in the debugger to see the real value of a string:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That isn't actually encoded with `\"`. That is literally a string whose contents are `" teetete  "`. In order to display it, or compile the string, you have to escape the quotes, which is why you have:

```
string s = "\" teetete \"";
```

A string that has backslash quote in it, i.e. `\"` will *actually* look like this:

```
string s = "\\\" teetete \\\"";
```

That is, one set of `\\` for a literal `\` and `\"` for a literal `"`. If you want to replace *that*, then it's almost what you wrote:

```
string t = s.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

That will convert any `\"` in your string to `"`, which I'm guessing is what you actually want, unless you're printing it out into some VB.NET code, in which case `"\"\""` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do, but it sounds like you have an XML string that contains a double-quote character (being displayed as `\"` in the debugger) and you need to replace it with `&quot;` to allow the XML parser to understand it.  In which case a simple call to `.Replace()` may be enough (although I imagine in reality there are edge cases that will need to be resolved with something more complex).